# kotlin distinct() or distinctBy {} from 2 existing arrays

Tags: kotlin, duplicates, distinct

Trying to understand distinct() and distinctBy function to check duplicates. 
when i try "distinct" with list of strings, it works fine. 
when i try it with Type "Any" with custom class NO luck :( 
can anyone please help me understand?

```
    var a = ArrayList<Any>()
    val terry = Person("Terry",13)
    val joe = Person("Joe", 20)
    val sam1 = Person("Sam",33 )
    a.add(terry)
    a.add(joe)
    a.add(sam1)

    var b = ArrayList<Any>()
    val valdi = Person("Valdi",55)
    val tak = Person("Tak", 54)
    val sam2 = Person("Sam",33 )
    b.add(valdi)
    b.add(tak)
    b.add(sam2)

    a.addAll(b)

    val c = a.distinct() 
    println(c) //prints all 6 items. sam1 and sam2 is duplicated.
```

Comment: I tried your code on [Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/) and it does not duplicate `sam1` and `sam2` with `Person` being a `data class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only issue I can think of is that your `Person` class is not a data class or it does not have the proper Primary constructor.

```
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    var age: Int
)
```

If your Person class is like that, then:

```
fun findDistinct() {
    val a = ArrayList<Any>()
    val terry = Person("Terry", 13)
    val joe = Person("Joe", 20)
    val sam1 = Person("Sam", 33)
    a.add(terry)
    a.add(joe)
    a.add(sam1)

    val b = ArrayList<Any>()
    val valdi = Person("Valdi", 55)
    val tak = Person("Tak", 54)
    val sam2 = Person("Sam", 33)
    b.add(valdi)
    b.add(tak)
    b.add(sam2)

    a.addAll(b)

    val c = a.distinct()
    println(c)
}
```

Will result in:

> [Person(name=Terry, age=13), Person(name=Joe, age=20),
>   Person(name=Sam, age=33), Person(name=Valdi, age=55), Person(name=Tak,
>   age=54)]

Like you expected

BTW, having `data class` means that class automatically generates the `equals(), hashCode(), toString(), copy()` methods. **Also -** Note that the compiler only uses the properties defined inside the primary constructor for the automatically generated functions. To exclude a property from the generated implementations, declare it inside the class body.

Comment: Hi, how about removing "Sam" from `val sam2` ? because `val sam1` has existing value for "Sam" ?

Answer (score 3):

`String` defines `equals()` and `hashCode()` properly so that objects with the same contents are considered equal.  Your `Person` class should do so (either directly or by using `data class`) to make `distinct()` and `distinctBy()` work properly.

The default implementation of these methods in `Any`, just like Java's `Object`, treats each instance as different from any other.

Comment: (Short but sweet :-)  OP should note that `Any` defines `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods which treat each object as different from every other, so that's what you get it you _don't_ override them.